# ¿Es correcto añadir enlaces de referencia que estén en otros idiomas?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, respuesta, idiomas

¿Es correcto postear y responder usando enlaces en idioma inglés como referencia? No hablo solo de enlaces en otros sitios de Stack Exchange sino en sitios de documentación y referencia bibliográfica también.

En mi opinión se debería recomendar en algún lugar de la ayuda que se intente buscar referencias en idioma español primero y, en caso de que no se encuentren, que se usen las referencias en inglés. Creo que el lugar más apropiado sería en [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Por supuesto que van a haber referencias canónicas que no se van a poder encontrar en otro idioma, pero muchas veces con un pequeño esfuerzo se pueden encontrar buenas referencias en español así que, en mi opinion, vale la pena animar a los desarrolladores a que usen las referencias correctas para tener una experiencia más completa en el sitio.

Comment: me parece interesante lo que dices, te digo lo que yo alguna vez realice, busque la documentacion de una herramienta de GNU al no encontrar nada en español puse el link al sitio en ingles pero indique que era en ingles puedes ver el caso en cuestio aqui -> http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479/buscar-todos-los-archivos-que-contienen-una-cadena-de-texto-en-linux/1485#1485 Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Tu solución me parece muy buena ya que te especifica de antemano lo que vas a encontrarte. Por increible que parezca hay personas, yo conozco algunas, que son incapaces de leerse un artículo en inglés; asi que el lector puede escoger si continua leyendo los posts o salta al articulo de referencia.

Comment: También se podría poner el link con una traducción automática del traductor de Google.

Comment: @Rubén (sugerencia) ya que haces un _bump_ de preguntas antiguas para añadirles etiquetas, puedes aprovechar para corregir otras cosas pendientes que tengan.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Es inadecuado proporcionar enlaces a páginas en inglés u otro idioma distinto del español?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1605/es-inadecuado-proporcionar-enlaces-a-p%c3%a1ginas-en-ingl%c3%a9s-u-otro-idioma-distinto-d)