# ¿Podría añadirse un indicador de idioma en los enlaces?

Tags: característica-nueva, formato, enlaces

Alguna vez ha surgido la duda de si un enlace a un idioma diferente al oficial de la página es aceptable:

- [¿Es inadecuado proporcionar enlaces a páginas en inglés u otro idioma distinto del español?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1605/es-inadecuado-proporcionar-enlaces-a-p%C3%A1ginas-en-ingl%C3%A9s-u-otro-idioma-distinto-d).
- [¿Es correcto añadir enlaces de referencia que estén en otros idiomas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319/es-correcto-a%C3%B1adir-enlaces-de-referencia-que-est%C3%A9n-en-otros-idiomas).

Mi opinión la compartí en el primero de los enlaces:

> La página de SOes se espera que el contenido sea en Español (de ahí el nombre) así que si algo no está en ese idioma opino que DEBE indicarse.

Durante un tiempo he seguido dicha premisa, anexando un icono de idioma al enlace:

- [stackoverflow.com [image]](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Pero es bastante incómodo de usar:

> ```
> [enlace en inglés <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/ae/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg/23px-Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg.png"/>](url)
> ```

Y además el recurso (originario de la wikipedia) podría cambiar de lugar, haciendo que el icono desapareciese.

---

Me gustaría proponer que se pudiese especificar el idioma en el enlace:

> ```
> [enlace en inglés](url|idioma)
> ```

Para añadir algún tipo de ayuda visual al usuario que vaya a hacer click en dicho enlace desde la página SOes.

Comment: DIOS TE OIGA...

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' como primer paso está bien, pero es un parche no una solución. Crear el enlace con el icono del idioma seguirá siendo suficientemente tedioso como para que salga más a cuenta no añadir el icono de idioma.

Comment: Hay un sitio Web que recién conocí de casualidad que fue destinado para publicar imágenes en Internet para que posteriormente pueda ser insertado. La página es [imgBB - Subir Imágenes](https://imgbb.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Sobre añadir imágenes, Es evidente que una imagen es un elemento visual rápido de reconocer, pero el texto ofrece ventajas que no tiene la imagen:

- se ve en cualquier formato
- se ve si la gente tiene deshabilitada la carga de imágenes
- permite buscarse más fácilmente
- permite la lectura para la gente que tiene lectores de pantalla

De hecho por ello pedimos a los usuarios que suban texto de código y no imágenes ([fuente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/83)).

---

Por ello, creo que en lugar de poner imágenes una solución más rápida y mantenible es añadir subtextos:

```
hola <sub>en inglés</sub>
```

Que se ven así:

> hola <sub>en inglés</sub>

La opción de especificarlo con el formato `[enlace en inglés](url|idioma)` podría hacer esta parte automática, así que seguro que sería útil.

---

En caso de querer seguir con las imágenes, creo que como primer paso sería bueno que subieras la imagen a imgur, para evitar que un cambio en Wikimedia rompa tantos enlaces.