# Respuestas y Preguntas que utilicen recursos o están relacionadas a la Deep Web son Aceptables?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, respuesta

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_profunda

Según la definición en Wikipedia, la deep web o Internet profunda, son las paginas web privadas o que requieren algún tipo de código para su acceso y por lo tanto no son indexadas por lo buscadores.

todos conocemos que en esta red de paginas hay mas cosas Ilegales que Legales. pero esto no descarta que con el conocimiento adecuado se puedan encontrar recursos que no se han publicado en la internet superficial.

como temas relacionados a la Programación y a la Seguridad Informática.

Mi pregunta es sencilla: SOes acepta preguntas y respuestas que estén relacionados a la Deep Web o recursos en ella?

Obviamente que tomando en cuenta que el contenido sea Legal y este orientado a la programación.

Comment: justo iba a preguntar esto >_<

Comment: jejejeje suelo adelantarme...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las publicaciones deben ser "autocontenidas", en otras palabras, estas deben ser claras para los expertos de las etiquetas sin necesidad de tener que consultar material externo no importa que este sea de Internet superficial o profunda (tampoco debe requerirse consultar material no disponible digitalmente)

Pueden incluir enlaces a cualquier contenido relacionado siempre y cuando este sea relevante con base en el contexto de la pregunta y no sea spam / malicioso.

Relacionado

- [¿Es correcto añadir enlaces de referencia que estén en otros idiomas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319/65)
- [¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/958/65)